# Document Not Writing InnerHTML to DIV

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

*Update* I have corrected the error. Aside from a few spelling errors, there were a few syntax errors that weren't apparent. I figured out how to use Firefox's Firebug to spot the rest.

Thanks all who took the time to read my newb post.

Need some help with my code. I have another version with fewer questions that works fine. I can't seem to find where this one is broken. The problem I'm having is nothing shows up in the DIV after entering/changing the form fields. The reset button works correctly. Also any suggestions for scripting software is appreciated.

Thanks,

Strutte2

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function processForm() {
                var customer_Name = document.configInfo.customername.value;
                var order_Number = document.configInfo.ordernumber.value;
                var base_Model = document.configInfo.basemodel.value;
                var install_Country = document.configInfo.basemodel.value;
                var install_State = document.configInfo.installstate.value;
                var pump_Type = document.configInfo.pumptype.value;
                var Style = document.configInfo.style.value;
                var Blender = document.configInfo.blender.value;
                var specify_Side = document.configInfo.specifyside.value;
                var grades_Products = document.configInfo.gradesproducts.value;
                var hoses_Nozzles = document.configInfo.hosesnozzles.value;
                var payment_Interface = document.configInfo.paymentinterface.value;
                var meter_Type = document.configInfo.metertype.value;
                var fuel_Combinations = document.configInfo.fuelcombinations.value;
                var fuel_Inlet1 = document.configInfo.fuelinlet1.value;
                var fuel_Inlet2 = document.configInfo.fuelinlet2.value;
                var fuel_Inlet3 = document.configInfo.fuelinlet3.value;
                var vapor_Recovery = document.configInfo.vaporrecovery.value;
                var remote_Filter = document.configInfo.remotefilter.value;
                var hydrosorb_Strainer = document.configInfo.hydrosorbstrainer.value;
                var junction_Box = document.configInfo.junctionbox.value;
                var hose_Handling = document.configInfo.hoseretraction.value;
                var nozzle_Activation = document.configInfo.nozzleactivation.value;
                var Hoses = document.configInfo.hoses.value;
                var Nozzles = document.configInfo.nozzles.value;
                var payment_Platform = document.configInfo.paymentplatform.value;
                var Display = document.configInfo.display.value;
                var soft_Keys = document.configInfo.softkeys.value;
                var ethernet_Options = document.configInfo.ethernetoptions.value;
                var payment_Keypad = document.configInfo.ethernetoptions.value;
                var card_Reader = document.configInfo.cardreader.value;
                var sales_Volume = document.configInfo.salesvolume.value;
                var unit_Price = document.configInfo.pricedisplay.value;
                var preset_Keypad = document.configInfo.presetkeypad.value;
                var stop_Button = document.configInfo.stopbutton.value;
                var Totalizers = document.configInfo.totalizers.value;
                var Intercom = document.configInfo.intercom.value;
                var lock_Options = document.configInfo.lockoptions.value;
                var security_Switches = document.configInfo.securityswitches.value;
                var dallas_Reader = document.configInfo.dallasreader.value; 
                var Valance = document.configInfo.valance.value;
                var custom_Panel = document.configInfo.custompanel.value;   
`               var Packaging = document.configInfo.packaging.value;
                var graphics_Spec = document.configInfo.graphicsspec.value;
                var product_Ids = document.configInfo.productids.value;
                var Language = document.configInfo.language.value;
                var auto_Discount = document.configInfo.autodiscount.value;
                var keypad_Assembly = document.configInfo.keypadassembly.value;
                var model_String = document.configInfo.modelstring.value;
                var CSR = document.configInfo.csr.value;
                var phone_Ext = document.configInfo.phoneext.value; 


                var holdInfo =  '<div> Customer Name: ' + customer_Name + '</div>' +
                            '<div> Order Number:' + order_Number + '</div>' +
                        '<div> Base Model: ' + base_Model + '</div>' + 
                        '<div> Installation Country ' + install_Country + '</div>' + 
                        '<div> Installation State ' + install_State + '</div>' + 
                        '<div> Pump Type:' + pump_Type + '</div>' + 
                        '<div> Style: ' + Style+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Blender: ' + Blender+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Specify Side: ' + specify_Side+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> No. Grades/Products: ' + grades_Products+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> No. Hoses/Nozzles: ' + hoses_Nozzles+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Payment Interface: ' + payment_Interface+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Meter Type: ' + meter_Type+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Fuel Combinations: ' + fuel_Combinations+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Fuel Inlet 1: ' + fuel_Inlet1+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Fuel Inlet 2: ' + fuel_Inlet2+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Fuel Inlet 3: ' + fuel_Inlet3+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Vapor Recovery: ' + vapor_Recovery+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Remote Filter: ' + remote_Filter+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Hydrosorb Strainer: ' + hydrosorb_Strainer+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Junction Box: ' + junction_Box+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Hose Handling: ' + hose_Handling+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Nozzle Activation: ' + nozzle_Activation+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Hoses: ' + Hoses+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Nozzles: ' + Nozzles+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Payment Platform: ' + payment_Platform+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Display: ' + Display+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Soft Keys: ' + soft_Keys+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Ethernet Options: ' + ethernet_Options+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Payment Keypad: ' + payment_Keypad+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Card Reader: ' + card_Reader+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Sales Volume: ' + sales_Volume+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Unit Price Display: ' + unit_Price+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Preset Keypad: ' + preset_Keypad+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Stop Button:  ' + stop_Button+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Totalizers: ' + Totalizers+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Intercom:  ' + Intercom+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Lock Options: ' + lock_Options+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Security Switches: ' + security_Switches+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> IDS (Dallas) Reader: ' + dallas_Reader+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Valance: ' + Valance+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Extra Custom Panel: ' + custom_Panel+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Packaging: ' + Packaging+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Graphics Spec & #: ' + graphics_Spec+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Product IDs: ' + product_Ids+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Language: ' + Language+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Automatic Discount: ' + auto_Discount+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Keypad Assembly: ' + keypad_Assembly+ '</div>' +
                        '<div> Model String: ' + model_String + '</div>' +
                        '<div> CSR: ' + CSR + '</div>' +
                        '<div> Phone Ext: ' + phone_Ext + '</div>';

                    document.getElementById("copyfield").innerHTML = holdInfo;  

                        }

            function clearForm() {
                var blank = "";
                document.getElementById('copyfield').innerHTML = blank;
            }


        </script>
```

JSLint wasn't much help in defining the error.

Comment: why add extra css and html if its a javascript question

Comment: What is broken exactly?  When you do what, what doesn't happen?  Much more description of what is wrong and how to reproduce the problem, please.  Have you looked in the browser error console for script errors?

Comment: Right, that's a *lot* of code. If you want help (as opposed to a lot of 'tl;dr' followed by 'went somewhere else'), you need to reduce that to the *minimal* code necessary to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Run this with your browser's dev tools open. This has multiple typos and invalid names, and your dev tool's Console will tell you every one of them.

Comment: The http://validator.w3.org/ shows that there are 132 errors and 6 warning on your page.

Comment: @jeff - are any of the validator errors actually relevant to the question at hand?

Answer (score 1):

This line looks like a typo (misspelling of `configINfo`):

```
var install_State = document.configINfo.installstate.value;
```

The error console in your browser should show you the exact line where a script error occurs.  There well may be other errors too.

Comment: +1 for digging thru the trash to find the problem. i figured it'll be a typo

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one misspelling

CHANGE:

```
var install_State = document.configINfo.installstate.value;
```

TO:

```
var install_State = document.configInfo.installstate.value;
```

CHANGE:

```
var hose_Handling = document.configInfo.hosehandling.value;
```

TO:

```
var hose_Handling = document.configInfo.hoseretraction.value;
```

CHANGE:

```
var unit_Price = document.configInfo.unitprice.value;
```

TO:

```
var unit_Price = document.configInfo.pricedisplay.value;
```

Comment: Thanks, what tool do you use to debug?

Comment: [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) It`s a really good PHP IDE and cheap :)